# How to do sum on the elements from list of Objects in Scala in play html template?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am receiving csrList in my Play HTML Template, I want to Construct table in my HTML using csrList Object, and I want total of each element to be shown in TOTALs row.

I do not want to send Totals as one more object in List, I want to do totals in template only using scala's syntactic sugar

is it possible ?

e.g.  Play Template

```
@(csrList: List[CSR])
....
....
<table id="abc">
    <tr>
        <th></th>                        
        <th>LTC</th>
        <th>LTI</th>
        <th>LTS</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th> TOTALs </th>
        <th> ???? </th>
        <th> ???? </th>
        <th> ???? </th>
    </tr>

    @for(csr <- csrList) {
        <tr>
            <td> @(csr.name) </td>
            <td> @(csr.ltc) </td>
            <td> @(csr.lti) </td>
            <td> @(csr.lts) </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

for Ref. following is Object Structure

```
case class CSR(name: String, ltc: Int, lti : Long, lts : Double)

val csr1 = new CSR("A", 1, 10, 2.1)
val csr2 = new CSR("B", 2, 20, 3.2)
val csr3 = new CSR("C", 3, 30, 9.5)

val csrList = List(csr1 ,csr2 , csr3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr>
    <th> TOTALs </th>
    <th> @csrList.map(_.ltc).sum </th>
    <th> @csrList.map(_.lti).sum </th>
    <th> @csrList.map(_.lts).sum </th>
</tr>
```